# Chatbase group by locale

Tags: chatbase

I'm currently developing a simple messenger bot, which supports multiple languages.

Is it possible in chatbase to group conversations by user locale? Can I somehow include the locale in `message_received` request?

Is it OK to append the locale to the chatbase_fields.version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We plan to add arbitrary key:value pairs to the api when we release our redesigned backend in the coming months.  For now, there are a few solutions for separating your bot's messages.

1. You can create a separate bot for each locale, and send messages to each respective bot.
2. You can use the [version field](https://www.chatbase.com/documentation/report-filters#version) of the api to denote the locale and filter your metrics accordingly.

Comment: Interesting. I was thinking about using the version field too. My bot will support 10 locales in the future, I'm not sure if 10 versions wouldn't get messy in the version tab. Anyway, thanks for your answer, very exited for the new features coming up :)

Comment: @sean-pearson Any idea when this feature will be added? Using the version is gonna be messy in my case since I've got 50 chatbots per version, my current thought is not to store the version in the version field, but rather the chatbot's name so I can filter by name. (adding name + version is gonna limit me when I'll seek stats from all versions combined). So I could really use the feature :)

Comment: @Vadorequest We decided not to implement the additional filtering as the current platform and version filters proved to be sufficient for most of our users needs. For your use case, you could use the platform field for your various locales, and then add the versioning to the version filter. This way you could keep all of your message data under one Chatbase bot.